# Axios post request to route 'appName/v1/users/' (Djoser) throws 401 error but Postman doesn't

Tags: django, vue.js, rest, authentication, axios

I'm new to Django and trying to build basic `user authentication` with REST API and a Vue.js frontend. To send the request, I am using `axios`, which is configured first in a seperate composable `axios.js`:

```
import axios from 'axios'

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8000'
```

and used inside a **`register.vue`** component:

```
const submitRegistration = () => {
    axios.post('api/v1/users/', {username: 'userName', password: 'userPassword'})
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
        })
}
```

To make it simple, I'm sending a data-object with predefined strings, as you can see above. The request gets sent to one of the djoser routes in `projectName/urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('api/v1/', include('djoser.urls.authtoken')),
]
```

This however, throws a `401 Unauthorized Error`:

```
code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
config: {transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}
message: "Request failed with status code 401"
name: "AxiosError"
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: true, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
response: {data: {…}, status: 401, statusText: 'Unauthorized', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}
stack: "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401\n    at settle (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=a45c5ec0:1120:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=a45c5ec0:1331:7)"
```

I've configured **`settings.py`** like so:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'djoser'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    ...,
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:3000']
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
```

#### Edit:

The problem might be caused by `authToken`. In the root vue component `app.vue`, I am checking the store for an authentication token and setting an axios header accordingly:

```
onMounted(() => {
    if (store.authToken) {
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Token ${store.authToken}`
    }
})
```

If I remove this code, the error turns into `400 BAD_REQUEST`. Although I don't understand why one would need an `authToken` when registering a new user.

`store.authToken` is set during initialization:

```
import {reactive} from "vue";

export const store = reactive({
    authToken: localStorage.authToken ?? null,
})
```

and shoud be `null`, when a new user is registered.

#### Edit2:

I followed some advice and used `Postman` to send the post request to `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/` and it works. A new user is created.

Comment: 401 is quite explicit, you're either not sending the credentials or they are wrong. Debug it by checking your network tab + trying out with Postman/Insomnia. Debug the client-side then the backend.

Comment: @kissu Could you check out the `Edit` section?

Comment: The question is too broad, you can isolate the problem on your side, which is likely on back end. It should be reproducible with simple requests like Postman. No token is supposed to be needed during registration

Comment: @EstusFlask I've sent a `post request` with `Postman` to `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/` and everything works. A new user was registered. Any idea why it doesn't work with axios?

Comment: It's good that you found the problem eventually, but the question was unanswerable. It lacked https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and didn't show the respective LS logic, there's no such thing as `localStorage.authToken`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My authentication check in the vue root component `app.vue` was flawed:

```
<script setup>
onMounted(() => {
    if (store.authToken) {
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Token ${store.authToken}`
    }
})
</script>
```

`store.authToken` always returned true despite being `null` because it was fetched from `localStorage` being a `string`. `JSON.parse()` solved the problem.